# Self::Many relation in yii

Tags: yii

Having two cloumn name having same

My Coding,

```
'usertile' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserTile', 'tile_id',
            'condition'=>'usertile.tile_id IS NULL'),
```

tile_id column name having same in that Usertitle table and Question table.

I want once tile_id in usertitle table mean that id value not showing in view list question table.

Now I got error like this,

```
 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'tile_id' in where clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `tbl_question` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_user_tile` `usertile` ON (`usertile`.`tile_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (is_deleted = :deleteflag and is_sample = :sampleFlag and tile_id IS NOT NULL) AND (usertile.tile_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: could you show the function that calls the query

Comment: Where do you set this condition `is_deleted = :deleteflag and is_sample = :sampleFlag and tile_id IS NOT NULL` ? You need to set alias in it too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

```
Column 'tile_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

and relation is right.

Check where you execute this query and other conditions added to query.